# Preventing crashes when enumerating objects while writing to them

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have a multithreaded application that uses a mutable dictionary.  The dictionary is being written to multiple times a second.  Each time it's written to, it is also enumerated directly afterwards.  The updated dictionary is connected to a published input on a Quartz Composer composition directly after being updated.  When updates happen very frequently, I see a crash when the we are trying to enumerate the object while writing to it at the same time.

```
if( self.dictEvent && [ [ self.renderer inputKeys ] containsObject: @"Event" ] )
{
    @synchronized( self.dictEvent )
    {
        [ self.renderer setValue: self.dictEvent forInputKey: @"Event" ];               
    }
}
```

It crashes on:

```
[ self.renderer setValue: self.dictEvent forInputKey: @"Event" ];
```

I know that this line enumerates and serializes the dictionary as it's passed to the QC composition.

I have tried to use `@synchronized` on both the writes to the dictionary and on this location, where it's being enumerated.  That hasn't been successful.  I'm unclear if `@sychronized` only protects threads from running the *same* block of code, or if it can prevent threads from running *any* block of code synchronized on the same object.

If I replace the offending line with: NSLog(@"Event: %@", self.dictEvent); I get the following message:

2014-11-01 10:48:02.679 Flocaster[24583:8446817] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFDictionary: 0x618000e6ed00> was mutated while being enumerated.'

Any tips you can provide area greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Adam

Comment: ```self.renderer``` is the dictionary being enumerated. Right? But when you synchronize, you use ```@synchroized(self.dictEvents)```. You didn't provide any mutual exclusion over ```self.renderer```.

Comment: Show the code that is doing the iteration. And why do you say it is crashing on the call to `setValue:forInputKey:` when it is probably the iteration that is crashing?

Comment: It's not my code that is enumerating. It happens automatically when dictionaries are attached to published inputs QC compositions.  They are serialized, and then transferred into QC.   I can also NSLog(@"Event: %@", self.dictEvent), and it will crash there too.  More detail added above.

Comment: @MohannadA.Hassan I thought it was dictEvent that was being enumerated, but you might be right.  If that's the case, it doesn't explain why it crashes when I replace the setValue with the NSLog of just self.dictEvent.  How could that be?

Comment: @MohannadA.Hassan I'm pretty sure it's not renderer that is being enumerated and crashing.  I get the log message even when I'm not setting the value of the renderer.  I think it has to be the dictEvent dictionary is crashing, because it crashes on the NSLog entry where that is the only value I log.

Comment: @AdamFenn Okay, but still ```@synchronized(self.dectEvents)``` isn't going to solve your problems. It will only allow a single thread to be in all block synchronized by ```self.dectEvents``` at once. It, however, will not prevent two threads from accessing the object itself  in the same. **My suggestion** is to send a copy of ```self.dectEvents``` to the 3rd party code that mutates the object.